# User friendly embeddable HTML/JavaScript hi-res image editor

Tags: javascript, image, html, image-processing, aviary

I've been playing with this rather spiffing [online embeddable image editor from Aviary](http://www.aviary.com/), and it does exactly what I need it to, namely:

- embeddable in my site as HTML/JS
- reasonably priced
- only basic, fun features
- completely idiot proof so even the most ham-fisted can thrash their way to something passable; or to put it another way, I don't want/need a traditional image editing interface like Photoshop - the way that Aviary have done it is pretty much spot on for my needs

However, in the documentation, they indicate that this is only suitable for web-resolution images, while I need to allow users to edit hi-res images as they will eventually be sent to a printer.

Does anyone know of anything comparable to this Aviary editor that can work with hi-res images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, it turns out that if you pay for the Enterprise version of the software, then full resolution is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [pixlr](http://pixlr.com/)?  As far as I'm aware, that editor is hi-res-capable.

Comment: I did have a look at that, and for what it is it looks great, but unfortunately it is way too advanced for my needs.